# Unauthorized error in Talend REST Client

Tags: mongodb, web-services, rest, talend, talend-mdm

I'm using Talend ESB 6.3 version & trying to pull the data from HP ALM to MongoDB. The below is my job,
[image]
In my job, I've started from "tMongoDBConnection --> tRESTClient --> tExtractXMLField --> tXMLMap --> tMongoDBOutput".

In the REST Client component throwing Exception- HTTP 401 Unauthorized.

How to resolve this issue?

My Issues is:

[image]

Comment: Can you put a screen of your trestclient component?

Answer (score 0):

This response indicates the server is attempting to authenticate you, and you are failing the authentication. Look in the `tRestClient` component and you can  see that Talend offers several out of the box options.  You need to find out what protocol the server is using.   You can use tools such as fiddler and examine the http headers, or first work out your connection issues using [SOAPUI](https://www.soapui.org/)  but chances are you are going to need a username and password, so your best bet is to reach out to your contact at the server end and simply ask for the credentials.